# want to create a function in react that creates recipe components when supplied with an array of instructions and another parameter as name of recipe

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am reading "Learning React" by O'Reilly. In this they have stated that we can create components by making a function called "component creating function" and in this function we can supply the required parameters as *second parameter* to `React.createElement` function. I did the same but I am getting no output. What is the best way to create such a components creating function?

```js
var a = ['warm water', 'put egg to boil', 'boil finishes', 'scrape off shell'],
  b = 'making eggs',
  recipeArray = [],
  name

function recipeWriter() {
  return React.createElement(
    'section', {
      className: 'recipe'
    },
    React.createElement('h3', {
      className: 'recipeName',
      key: 0
    }, name),
    recipeArray.map((i, j) =>
      React.createElement('li', {
        key: j
      }, i)
    )
  )
}

let el = ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(recipeWriter, {
    recipeArray: a,
    name: b
  }, null), document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
#root {
  background-color: cornsilk;
  font: bold 1em monospace
}

.recipe {
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 30px;
}

.recipeName {
  font: 2em monospace;
  color: red;
}

.steps {
  color: darkgreen
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

**I want my output like this ->**

```js
var recipeArray = ['warm water', 'put egg to boil', 'boil finishes', 'scrape off shell'],
  name = 'making eggs'

function recipeWriter() {
  return React.createElement(
    'section', {
      className: 'recipe'
    },
    React.createElement('h3', {
      className: 'recipeName',
      key: 0
    }, name),
    recipeArray.map((i, j) =>
      React.createElement('li', {
        key: j
      }, i)
    )
  )
}

let el = ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(recipeWriter, null, null), document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
#root {
  background-color: cornsilk;
  font: bold 1em monospace
}

.recipe {
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 30px;
}

.recipeName {
  font: 2em monospace;
  color: red;
}

.steps {
  color: darkgreen
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing the variables from the `prop` which are passed to your `recipeWriter` component.

```
function recipeWriter(props) {
   const recipeArray = props.recipeArray;
   const name = props.name
}
```

Or more simply written using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
function recipeWriter({ recipeArray, name }) {
}
```

*Also you can remove the recipeArray and name from the top of your file as they are available in the component*

---

Whenever you call `React.createElement` the 2nd parameter is the `props`. For instance in your code:

```
React.createElement(recipeWriter, {
    recipeArray: a,
    name: b
  }, null)
```

Here you are passing the `recipeArray` and `name` to your component. Those props are accessible using the 1st parameter of your functional component.

See [documentation for `React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)
and [documentation for a functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)

Comment: Thanks, it worked beautifully by both PROPS OBJECT and DESTRUCTURING METHODS